# Background draws black on the runtime

Tags: android, background

I'M trying to develop an application for Android but I have some problem with it. I have a main RelativeLayout which has a nice background image. When I run it via AVD (over eclipse) it works and looks fine but when I try to test it on my Galaxy Nexus phone background is pure black. How can I solve this?

Main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GPRelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gempouchbg"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

It's merged with some header layout.

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/headerMerge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    layout="@layout/header" />
```

Can anyone help me? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, background image dimensions was way too big I needed to crop it to 640x640 and it fixed my problem. Hope it helps to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using an image for setting background of relativelayout it must look same in all the cases.

and if you are not satisfied with your background then you must change the image in your case and try.

place your image in drawable folder and try once.

Comment: Background image is not showing at all, instead I get a black background. Thats the problem.